# How to change the CSS "animation-delay" property in D3?

Tags: html, css, d3.js

Project: To create radial progress bars to initiate at a specific time; i.e. time-initiated progress bars. The look will be like the radial progress bars are chasing each other.

I am attempting to change the CSS Property "animation-delay" using D3. My code seems ineffective. What changes would make the D3 code change the CSS property?

Here is a D3 code snippet:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
//Assume we have a function that calculates the amount of time lapsed since the last departure
//function seconds_since_depart {(return time=(now.time - last.depart.time))}

var time=42;
// a negated time is equal to a progress bar being initiated 42 seconds ago
//but the following line doesn't work
d3.selectAll(".progress__value__a").style({"animationDelay": "-" + time + "s"})

</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vwetzkjy/

Thanks

Comment: Hello & welcome to stackoverflow. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: ksav, Yes. It is in the jsfiddle. What detail would you be looking for?

Comment: What exactly have you tried with d3?

Comment: I rewrote the question with the requested D3 code attempt.

Comment: I really don't understand what d3 has to do with this. You are just trying to set a css value with javascript.

Comment: You are right, D3 would have been overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is not using d3, but as you have no data to drive your document, I'm not convinced that you actually need to use d3 to achieve this.

```js
var time = 10;
const selector = `.progress__value__a`
const progressBar = document.querySelector(selector)
progressBar.style.animationDelay = `${time*-1}s`
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #f9faff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.demo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


.progress {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.progress__value {
  stroke-dasharray: 766.5486;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  animation: progress 39.86s linear infinite;
}

.progress__value__a {
  stroke-dasharray: 766.5486;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  animation: progress 39.86s linear infinite;
}


@keyframes progress {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 766.5486;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <svg class="progress" height="500" width="500">
    <circle cx="260" cy="230" r="122" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="4" fill="white" />
    <circle class="progress__value" cx="260" cy="230" r="122" stroke="#009900" stroke-width="5" opacity=".71" fill="#f9faff" stroke-dasharray="766.5486" stroke-dashoffset="766.5486" />
    <circle class="progress__value__a" cx="260" cy="230" r="122" stroke="#ff3a00" stroke-width="5" opacity=".71" fill="#f9faff" stroke-dasharray="766.5486" stroke-dashoffset="766.5486" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k_sav/fjhtowpv/)